# Is {1,2,9} a subgroup of ({1,2,4,8,9,13,15,16},$\times_{17}$)?

Tags: abstract-algebra

The subgroup {1,2,9} contains the identity element, also, each of its element has its inverse but how about closure? Is it correct to deduce closure from the fact that $2 \times_{17} 9 = 1$?

Comment: What about $2\times_{17}2$?

Comment: $2\times_{17}2=4$ and $4$ is not in {1,2,9} and therefore, not closed! Forgot that one, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:If $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ then $O (H)$ divides $O (G)$

Answer (score 0):

The subset {1,2,9} is not closed under $\times_{17}$ because $2\times_{17}2=4$ and $4$ is not in {1,2,9}.